# Installing default font from "Font Installer" app only changes partially. How to apply it globally?

Tags: system, fonts

I rooted my LG G2 D802 and changed font using [Font Installer ★ Root ★](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.font.installer). Then I changed my mind and changed the font with the one which came already in the phone. But the font hasn't changed in the whole smartphone.

The rooted font exists in some apps like Play Store and the stock one in the rest of the smartphone!

What can I do?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: and here is the rooted font]  [image: IMG: here is the stock font]

Comment: Rebooted the phone? Or perform a factory reset

Comment: i did both! But nothing happens!

Comment: I think the issue is, the selected font applies to all system fonts, but the original doesn't cover all of them (which is strange, but possible). Anyway, good to know that you noticed the FAQ to backup on the app description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find someone with the same phone as you (rooted) and find the font files and send them to yourself and copy them into the location of your font files and do a reboot. Worked for me. Or you can find a dump for your phone and download those files and find the font in there and place those into your font files. (Friend did that and it worked as well. I have warned people not to download that app as it ruins the font settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer! But at the end i forced to reflash the same rom on my android. I found out that i have to keep a backup of my fonts if i use the  Font Installer ★ Root ★ (i didn't know that!) So everything is ok now!

Comment: @Nikos considered posting your comment as an answer, since that solves your issue personally. [Self-answering](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is also encouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out the solution! First of all before you change font from a rooted app you have to backup all your stock fonts! I didn't do that and then this problem occurred! After some research the only way to fix this (if you don't have a backup) is to reflash the stock ROM! Thanks everyone for the help!